# My website redirects to an unknown website

Tags: virus, url-redirection

I coded my own website and uploaded to a host. Some days ago I realised that in specific page suddenly redirects to an unknown websites, until 3-4 redirects.

The redirects are: mywebsite.com/*smth*-> es.webtraffapi01.selfip.com/*smth* -> 52342123.g03.info/?p=*smth* -> es.webtraff.com/*smth*

I have checked the file which gives me the problem and I don't see any redirect to a unknown website. I have downloaded all the files with FileZilla and checked with Avast Antivirus and Virustotal website and 0 virus appeared.

I don't what can be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

additional, to what RyPeck said, you should check, if a .htaccess - file might be found in your docroot, containing malicious redirects (if so, the attacker has write-access to your docroot and your server is probably hacked)

- is this url you mentioned (mywebsite.com/smth) a valid url for your site?
- what are your running for a software? (eg wordpress, drupal'n'such)
- is it static (html) or dynamic (php), is content loaded from a database?

Comment: i dont have htacces file. reference to your question, i dont use any cms, i just coded from 0 my website. every file is html with php and smth of jquery and some content is loaded from database. i dont understand the first question

Comment: >  "i dont understand the first question." ok, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know of three ways for an attacker to trigger a website redirection on content from a server. If your website has any of the following -

- Accepts user input
- Advertisements
- Content loaded from a database

It is possible a third party may have found the means to insert content on your page that will render as HTML/Javascript and trigger a redirection.

Just because AntiVirus programs don't report an error doesn't mean that something malicious is going on. Try running `wget` with the `--max-redirect` option set to 0. See where on the page the redirection is.

Comment: i accept user input, i dont have any advertisment, and i load content from database BUT the page which gives this problem doesn't load any thing from DB. 
I tried wget with that parameter, but the redirect only can happen if you are logged in, so website only redirects when a button is clicked which only appear when you are logged in.

Comment: Is there data you load when logged in that comes out of the database?